# Algorithm selection for an Arduino control function

Tags: multidimensional-array, arduino, complexity-theory

I have a function that has to do two things:

- Traverse an `n*n*n` array
- Update pins depending on state of the array

This function will be running repeatedly.

I have two algorithms to perform the work of the function:

- First, it traverses the complete array and has complexity `Th(n**3)`, but it has minimal `digitalWrite` operations, roughly Th(n) (as certain pin states depend on neighbouring pin states).
- Second, it traverses parts of the array and has `Th(n**2)`, but it has maximum `digitalWrite` operations `Th(n**2)`.

Question I am having:

- For small `n`, does it even matter which approach I take?
- How expensive is a `digitalWrite` operation as compared to a three dimensional array access operation? (As optimizing one, leads to increased calls to the other.)

Comment: @PeterMortenson It might be incorrect British English, but it certainly is correct Indian English.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowledge of your specific function this can not be reasonable answered. It is even unclear if it matters. In general for performance problems the proper approach is to implement both ways and to measure. Especially for small n you can not derive something like this from theory.

My suggestion would be to go for the algorithm that is simpler to implement and understand. Once it works you can try if the performance is sufficient. If it is then fine. Problem solved. Otherwise you can start to tweak and optimize.

If the digitalWrite performance is an issue you can always fall back to direct port manipulation. But as I already said: get it to work first.

If the array traversal is an issue you can always map the array into a lower dimensional array and adapt your traversal function. Often this results in performance improvements as well.